# differences iphone safari webkit vs mac safari

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, safari

i'm trying to create a website for iphones with the apple typical sliding menue effect.

on safari and firefox on my mac everything works pretty fine, but checking the page on my iphone safari made me wondering.

there's the link to the slider test...

[IphoneSliderTest](http://project.formplusmedia.de/iphone_slider/)

it would be nice if you could check the page on your iphone and on the browser on your computer too and tell me why this doesnt work on the iphone..

because of the slow internet connection of most iphones im trying to load the new  tag just when im clicking to another element by using ajax requests and jquery ( v 1.3.2 )...

anyone of you knows why its not working on iphone safari but on mac safari???

thx for the help and sorry for my bad english!! :)
-dani

Answer (score 4):

You should use [JQtouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) instead